# Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings in CI

Tags: database, codeigniter, mysqli, config, codeigniter-hmvc

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: /home/rehmantr/public_html/third_party/MX/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 94

Dear Sir,
I am facing this issue, my database.php file setting is below

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'hostname'; 

$db['default']['username'] = 'username';

$db['default']['password'] = 'password';

$db['default']['database'] = 'database';

$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';

$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';

$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;

$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;

$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;

$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';

$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';

$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';

$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

but still I am facing this issue,please help me.

I am using HMVC pattern of CI

Comment: is these `$db['default']['hostname'] = 'hostname'; 

$db['default']['username'] = 'username';

$db['default']['password'] = 'password';

$db['default']['database'] = 'database';
` you have specified are correct ?

Answer (score 0):

I think its a problem with your credentials, verify that user and password are correct and that the user has access to the database you specify in the settings.